# How Do I Grab And Put Primary Key Into Foreign Key In Another Table? PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

The tables are Accounts with A_ID (PRIMARY KEY), Username, Password and Messages with M_ID (PRIMARY KEY), Message, A_ID (FOREIGN KEY)

When a person sends a message I am using a SELECT statement to get the person's A_ID where their username = their username and then INSERT it into the table.

The full code is in the Paste below, it is quite messy, please forgive me for that. I'm working on a much cleaner version but I have to get this vital part first.

http://pastebin.com/e3aqGerw

Where I am really stuck is here ¬

```
if (isset($_POST['SendMessage'])) {
    $GetAID = "SELECT A_ID FROM Accounts WHERE Username='$CookieValue'";
    $ResultAID = $Connect->query($GetAID);
    echo $ResultAID;
    $Message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['Message']);
    $MessageSQL = "INSERT INTO Messages (M_ID, Message, A_ID) VALUES ('', '$Message', '$ResultAID')";

    if ($Connect->query($MessageSQL) === TRUE) {
        echo "Message Sent<BR/>";
    } else {
        echo "Error Sending Message<BR/>";
    }
}
```

My question is how do I put the A_ID into a variable and then INSERT it into the Messages table as the FOREIGN KEY to Accounts table's A_ID PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Your code needs to be *in the question*, not in a PasteBin.  And if you want us to help you with this, you need to take the time to format it.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Edited, if it's not enough let me know

Comment: Great.  Thanks.  Please indicate the error / issue that you are having.  Where does your code fail? What is the error?

Comment: Also, this is **wildly** insecure: `$SQL = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Username=$Username' AND Password='$PasswordHash'";` - you are vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, **and you should never** pass the password AND username in the query.  Execute a query using the username only, then compare the password hash from the database with the hash in PHP logic, **not in the query**.

Answer (score 0):

The Foreign Key requirement has to be handled on the SQL server. You will need to set up  a foreign key restraint.

Inserting the variable is easy.

```
    $MessageSQL = "INSERT INTO Messages (M_ID, Message, A_ID) VALUES ('', '".$Message."', '".$ResultAID['A_ID']."')";
```

Comment: I get this Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 53

Comment: What does your echo statement display?

Comment: Do you mean this? echo 'M_ID: ' . $Row['M_ID'] . ' Message: ' . $Row['Message'] . 'A_ID: ' . $Row['A_ID'] . '<BR>';

Answer (score 0):

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO Accounts (A_ID, Username, Password) VALUES ('', '$Username', '$PasswordHash')";
$Result = mysqli_query($Connect, $SQL);

$GET_last_ID = mysqli_insert_id($con);

$MessageSQL = "INSERT INTO Messages (M_ID, Message, A_ID) VALUES ('', '$Message', '$GET_last_ID')";
```

just add the `$GET_last_ID = mysqli_insert_id($Connect);` below `mysqli_query` and insert the variable `$GET_last_ID` to the next table. just like u see above. the code `$GET_last_ID = mysqli_insert_id($Connect);` will get the lastes inserted primary key id.

hope this help you

Comment: I still get an error somehow. Would you mind putting it inside the code I shared on Pastebin so I can make sure I'm doing it 100% correctly? Sorry.

Comment: Read the code in the question - your answer is dealing with the wrong part.  OP is having an issue getting the value from the DB, not getting an insert id.

Comment: sorry. but your code is kind of mess up . from my understanding you wanted to get the latest inserted ID from `$SQL = "INSERT INTO Accounts (A_ID, Username, Password) VALUES ('', '$Username', '$PasswordHash')";` this line of code?

Comment: or you want to get the `id` of the person who is logged in?